# AJAX and php JSON connect DB and retern values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am new in using AJAX i try to make a image buttons when click return a resualts from a query as JSON form. I make the image buttons and write an jQuery to test it when i click to show an alert and is work after i replase the alert with an AJAX but is not work. 
in php make a connection with db , execute the queries and make the JSON array
heare is the code of making the JSON array

The ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "routing.php",
                data: { data : JSON.stringify(ar)},
                dataType : "JSON",
                success: function(data){
                var jsonAr = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data);


        }
                    });
```

PHP file server side

```
//header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
 $obj = json_decode($_POST['data']);
 //some php operation
}
     echo $obj;
```

The code is work but give this error from server side from php
POST http://xxxx/xxxxxx/routing.php [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 39ms]

Comment: what means "is not work"? do you get any error? Have you already tried to debug and took a look at your response with firebug or a similar tool?

Comment: The error is need the beach , 'beach' , data:{"type":'beach'}

Answer (score 0):

i guess you don't need the `contentType` in the ajax:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

You can remove it to test.

---

See by default this is the content type for the jquery ajax:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and you are setting the content type to:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

so at the backend php you can't use `$_POST["type"];` because that is not available this way, instead you have to use:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$type = $data->type; // will let you get the posted "type"
```

Comment: i delete it but again nothing.